# Can't magin-top a div?

Tags: html, css, margin

I tried to add `magin-top` to a div style .. but it's not working

[image]

Here is the code

```css
.side {
  margin-left: 65%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.home {
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 62%;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

.home h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.side h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Just a template.</p>
</div>
<div class="side">
  <h1>Widget Header</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>Widget content.</p>
</div>
```

I expect the "side" div to be at the same line with "home" div

Comment: @Rayyan, please make a JSFiddle next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign float:left to an element,the element shifts to that direction and the other elements gets wrapped around it.If you inspect the page, you can see that .side covers the total width of the page and .home is sitting just over it.To make .side align with .home,minimise both the width of .home and the left margin of .side so that both of the div can be accomodated with the width of the page.Next apply float:left to .side, so that it can get aligned with .home . Here's a working solution:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
          .home {
           margin-left: 3%;
           margin-top: 3%;
           width: 50%;
           border: 1px solid;
           float: left; 
          }
        .side {
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        margin-right: 3%;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid;
        } 
        </style>
    </head>
<body>        
    <div class="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Just a template.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
    <h1>Widget Header</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Widget content.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link of a video that will give you a clear understanding about floats: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xara4Z1b18I

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home {
    margin-top: 0;
   //more code....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/tm1ps3jo/). if so, remove `margin-top` from `.home`

Answer (score 0):

i need it to be like this .. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZPsh.jpg

when i remove margin-top and add padding-top i get this .. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XocHg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using percentages for your margin-top properties (what exactly is 3% a percentage of?). You should instead consider using absolute pixel values, or wrap your two columns in another container for which would have a single unified margin-top.

On a side note (pardon the pun) your `side` element should also `float: right` if you wish it to carry out the same behaviour as `home`. Removing margin-left and setting a width will make it sit correctly beside the `home` column.

Koda